# Compiling multiple test files efficiently with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a C++ project with the following structure:

```
/Project
    Makefile
    /src (.cpp source files)
     ...
    /include (.h header files)
     ...    
    /libs 
     ...
    /build (.o object files)
     ...    
    /tests (target .cpp files I want to compile)
     test1.cpp
     test2.cpp
     test3.cpp
     ...    
    /bin (output directory for compiled files)
     ...
```

For the tests inside my test file, I would like to be able to

- Compile them individually, e.g. "make test1", "make test2"
- Compile them all at once

But I would like to be able to do this **without** needing to define new variables (e.g. TARGET1, TARGET2,...) for each new test file, nor add a bunch of new lines to my makefile for each new test file.

For example, right now I have something like:

```
CXX = g++
SRC_DIR = ./src
BUILD_DIR = ./build
LIB = -I libs
INC = -I include 

SRCS = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -name *.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%, $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(SRCS:.cpp=.o))


TARGET1 ?= test1.cpp
TARGET2 ?= test2.cpp
TARGET3 ?= test3.cpp

all: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) ./tests/$(TARGET1).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o ./bin/$(TARGET1)
        $(CXX) ./tests/$(TARGET2).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o ./bin/$(TARGET2)
        $(CXX) ./tests/$(TARGET3).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o ./bin/$(TARGET3)

$(TARGET1): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) ./tests/$(TARGET1).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o ./bin/$(TARGET1)

$(TARGET2): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) ./tests/$(TARGET2).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o ./bin/$(TARGET2)

$(TARGET3): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) ./tests/$(TARGET3).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o ./bin/$(TARGET3)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

which does the job, but isn't very scalable. How could I do this scalably?

Comment: You can define a multi-line macro using define/endef, then eval() it. Combined with patsubst, using this approach you can auto-generate all the rules for each target, automatically. It took me a while to plow through the GNU make documentation, when I did something similar, so I can't quite recall all the details off the top of my head, but it's definitely doable. Just a matter of investing time into reading, and re-reading, GNU make's info, until you fully wrap your brain around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make has some more tricks that you can use (not tested):

```
CXX = g++
SRC_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build
TEST_DIR = tests
BIN_DIR = bin
LIB = -I libs
INC = -I include

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

TESTS = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*.cpp)
TARGETS = $(patsubst $(TEST_DIR)/%.cpp,$(BIN_DIR)/%,$(TESTS))

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): $(BIN_DIR)/%: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(TEST_DIR)/$*.cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $^ -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

The main trick here is the [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) for `$(TARGETS)`: in the recipe `$*` expands as the stem of the pattern.  The other tricks are a simpler use of `patsubst` and the use of `wildcard` instead of the less efficient `shell find`. Note that this last one works only if your source files are flat in `src`, not if they are organized in a hierarchy of sub-directories.

But this does not answer your most tricky request: a way to invoke `make testX` instead of `make bin/testX`. So, here is the most tricky part:

```
SHORTERTARGETS = $(patsubst $(TEST_DIR)/%.cpp,%,$(TESTS))

.PHONY: $(SHORTERTARGETS)

# $(1): short target
define TARGETS_rule
$(1): $(BIN_DIR)/$(1)
endef
$(foreach t,$(SHORTERTARGETS),$(eval $(call TARGETS_rule,$(t))))
```

You can even use this `foreach-eval-call` to factorize other parts of your Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
SRC_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build
TEST_DIR = tests
BIN_DIR = bin
LIB = -I libs
INC = -I include

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

TESTS = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*.cpp)
TARGETS = $(patsubst $(TEST_DIR)/%.cpp,$(BIN_DIR)/%,$(TESTS))
SHORTERTARGETS = $(patsubst $(TEST_DIR)/%.cpp,%,$(TESTS))

.PHONY: all $(SHORTERTARGETS)

all: $(TARGETS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

# $(1): short target
define TARGETS_rule
$(1): $(BIN_DIR)/$(1)
$(BIN_DIR)/$(1): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(TEST_DIR)/$(1).cpp $(LIB) $(INC) $$^ -o $$@
endef
$(foreach t,$(SHORTERTARGETS),$(eval $(call TARGETS_rule,$(t))))
```

The most difficult to understand in this last version is the need of `$$`in the recipe (double expansion). But here the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) is your friend.